# No consigo obtener registros de mysql con resultset

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysqli, java-8

No consigo obtener registros de mysql con resultset, mi intencion es almacenar el contenido del registro obtenido a partir de la sentencia pero cuando pongo un punto de ruptura ahi justo peta y me salta al catch con el mensaje de excepcion "before start of result set" y nno entiendo que pasa cuando en los ejemplos de clase funciona perfectamente, ya hemos revisado las querys y todas funcionan correctamente en mysql y devuelven lo que tienen que devolver

```
public boolean estaUsuario(String correo, String password) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+
                "'"+ password+"'" + ";";
        Statement sentencia = this.getCon().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(query);
        int i=resultado.getInt(1);
        if (i==1) {
            query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+"'"+ password+"'" + ";";
            resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(query);
            String nombre=resultado.getString(1);
            System.out.println("Bienvenido " + nombre);
            sentencia.close();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("El usuario no esta registrado");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Algo fallo, contacta con el servicio tecnico. Disculpa las molestias");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
public class BDConecction {
private Connection con;
private String usuario="root";
private String password="borja123";
private String sURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mychat?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

public BDConecction() throws Exception{
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL,usuario,password);

}

/*public BDConecction(String usuario, String pass) throws Exception{
    //Class.forName ("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.password = pass;
    String sURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mychat?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL,this.usuario,this.password);
}*/

public Connection getCon() throws Exception {
    return con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL,usuario,password);
}
public boolean cerrarConexion(){
    try {
        con.close();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: lo unico que se me ocurre es que en el this.getCon no te este retornando de manera correcta. El resto del codigo esta correcto de acuerdo a lo que veo, podrias mostrar el metodo getCon y podriamos tener un mejor panorama del error para ayudarte.

Comment: Aun asi podrias revisar la documentacion de oracle y revisar si algo te hace falta https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: ya he subido la clase donde esta getCon() pero vamos que eso tambien funciona bien 100% comprobado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que no has movido el cursor del `ResultSet` a la primera posición. Por defecto el cursos se encuentra antes de la primera fila de resultados. Por tanto solo debes hacer uso del método [ResultSet#Next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()).

```
resultado.next();
int i=resultado.getInt(1);
```

Ahora, debes tener en cuenta que si la consulta no devuelve resultados vas a seguir teniendo problemas porque en dicho caso la llamada a `next()` no va a poder mover el cursor a ninguna fila (básicamente porque no hay). Por lo tanto el uso correcto de este método es preguntar si retorna `true` antes de acceder a los datos del `ResultSet`.

> Returns: `true` si la nueva fila actual es válida; `false` si no hay más filas

Este compartamiento también es útil si queremos recorrer todas las filas que hemos obtenido de una conulta hasta, ya que nos indica cuando hemos terminado.

En definitiva, tu código debe quedar como esto:

```
public boolean estaUsuario(String correo, String password) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+
                "'"+ password+"'" + ";";
        Statement sentencia = this.getCon().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(query);

        if (resultado.next()) {
            int i=resultado.getInt(1);
            if (i==1) {
                query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+"'"+ password+"'" + ";";
                resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(query);
                String nombre=resultado.getString(1);
                System.out.println("Bienvenido " + nombre);
                sentencia.close();
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("El usuario no esta registrado");
                return false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("La consulta no devolvió datos");
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Algo fallo, contacta con el servicio tecnico. Disculpa las molestias");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Actualización**

Me acabo de dar cuenta que si la primera consulta te retorna un 1 dentro haces otra consulta y tienes el mismo problema de que no mueves el cursor del `ResultSet` antes de accederlo.

```
public boolean estaUsuario(String correo, String password) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+"'"+ password+"'" + ";";
        Statement sentencia = this.getCon().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(query);

        if (resultado.next()) {
            int i=resultado.getInt(1);
            if (i==1) {
                query = "SELECT nombre FROM usuarios WHERE correo = " + "'"+correo+"'" + " AND contraseña = "+"'"+ password+"'" + ";";
                ResultSet resultado2 = sentencia.executeQuery(query);

                if (resultado2.next()) {
                    String nombre = resultado2.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("Bienvenido " + nombre);
                    sentencia.close();
                    return true;
                }               
            } else {
                System.out.println("El usuario no esta registrado");
                return false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("La consulta no devolvió datos");
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Algo fallo, contacta con el servicio tecnico. Disculpa las molestias");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, si es cierto que cuando meto un registro que no esta en la base de datos el programa reacciona correctamente pero cuando meto los datos que si estan registrados en la base de datos me sale el mismo error de "Before start of result set"

Comment: Y en ese caso el `next()` te retorna `true`? No puede ser. Si no obtienes datos de la consulta el `next()` retorna `false` y en caso contrario `true` lo que te garantiza que hay datos en el `ResultSet` y por ende no puede de ningún modo tener ese error. Asegúrate de que la consulta está devolviendo datos y que tienes tu código como el mío.

Comment: sisi es mas he copiado tu codigo y lo he pegado lo he probado y me da ese error, si quieres te paso captura de la base de datos y del output del progrma pero ya te digo las querys las he vuelto a probar en el mysql y devuelven bien pero es eso si meto datos que no existen funciona bien saltando al else pero si meto datos que existen en la BBDD me salta al catch con ese error "Before start of result set"

Comment: @BorjaLorenzo te acabo de actualizar la respuesta. Me parece que el error puede estar dentro, cuando ejecutas la otra consulta para obtener el nombre del usuario

Comment: pues no lo se voy a poner un punto de ruptura y te digo donde peta

Comment: el programa peta justa en esta linea:
"String nombre=resultado.getString(1);"
cuando llega aqui salta al catch y nno se por que si esta igual que la otra sentencia, estoy almacenandole el resultado en una variable

Comment: Me lo imaginé. Revisa la actualización que te puese donde agrego un `next()` antes de esa línea

Comment: Aparte del error de lectura, no entiendo por qué dos consultas  ¿? Si es para saber si hay registros bastaría con lanzar la 2ª consulta y verificar si el `rs` está o no vacío.

Comment: @A.Cedano, exacto, pero ese es otro asunto xD

Comment: Nunca es una buena idea leer un `ResultSet` dentro de otro `ResultSet`. Lo que ofrece JDBC es una especie de recurso y al tener dos abiertos podría ser problemático. En caso de que se justifique usar dos `rs` es mejor vaciar el primero en una variable, cerrarlo y luego leer el segundo.

Comment: Eso no es problemático en ningún sentido. Ambos recursos (ResultSet) son idependientes el uno del otro ya que corresponden a dos consultas diferentes. No obstante el código no me gusta ni un poco del modo planteado, pero prefiero no abordar este asunto ya que se aleja de la pregunta. Además que de mejorarlo quizá tenga que explicárselo por completo al OP.

Comment: si al final puse otra vez el resultado.next() debajo del executequery y funciona, muchisimas gracias nos has salvado de estar todo el dia aqui frustrado sin conseguir nada ^^